# Use CSS to make <button> and <a> look the same

Tags: css

I'd like to make <button> and <a> to look the same. I've found a similar post that suggests adding

```
box-sizing: content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
```

However, it still has a slight height difference when viewed in Firefox. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3HK8/3/). Any help?

Comment: No, @OneTrickPony, in firefox they are totally different.

Comment: The Twitter Bootstrap .btn class does this with button, anchor and input (type="submit") elements. I'd recommend having a look at their code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/H3HK8/22/

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
.btn::-moz-focus-inner
{
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This fixes the middle one, still working on the final input.

From here http://www.aheadcreative.com/removing-unwanted-button-padding-in-firefox/

**UPDATE**

I suspect for the final example you are falling victim to this http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/#.USzRd6Wcmzc

You can see the line height has no effect in this example http://jsfiddle.net/H3HK8/24/, even with !important added.

> And while trying to work around this rule, I discovered something that makes the situation a little more dire: browser-defined !important rules cannot be over-ruled by author-defined !important rules. This rule cannot be overruled by a CSS file, an inline style — anything.

Comment: It appears it has something to do with [FF overriding the line-height property](http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/#.USzQkG-KLQc)

Comment: Ha! 40 seconds too fast for me! I was editing my question as you commented!

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that all CSS properties are the same. So not only the box-sizing (which does not really do anything in itself), but also the padding, margin, line-height, font-size, background etc.

Comment: I think box-sizing defines the way borders are added. (i.e. inside or outside of the padding). If you look at my jsfiddle example, both the button and link use the same styling. Am I missing something?